# Can you follow a calendar?

Tags: newsfeed

I see that you can set up to be emailed for alerts on a calendar, but as our organization is trying to dissuade users from using email for business processes and use Sharepoint for their one stop shop for keeping up to date, this seems like low-hanging fruit.  I can't seem to find a way to get calendar updates into my newsfeed.  Does this feature just not exist?

Comment: It does not I'm afraid, not OOTB at least.

Comment: @RobertLindgren Bummer.  How you used any apps that accomplish this feature?

Comment: You can connect calendars to Outlook or subscribe to calendars via RSS, is that sufficient?

Comment: @PirateEric No, our users don't use outlook and we've been pushing the soical features of SP to drive users to use it more centrally.